# What HTTP status code return when user needs to be UNAUTHORIZED to access page

Tags: api, rest, http

I was wondering what HTTP status code should I return if user that is authorized tries to access page that should be accessible only by unauthorized users.

Currently I am just throwing 404, but was wondering if there is some common approach for this.

Comment: I am not sure this a "thing".  401 is for people not authorized to se a page but not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP Status Code **403 Forbidden** can be used when a request isn't allowed based on the user's identification, so I guess it can be used in this case.

However, have you also considered sending back a **Redirect** (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) to send the user to a different resource that might be more appropriate because they are authenticated?

This is a common method used to redirect authenticated users away from login pages to their home screens or profile page.

Also, for future reference, I think you might be referring to **autheNtication** (with a N, the process of verifying a users identity) instead of **authoriZation** (with a Z, the process of determining whether an authenticated user has access to a particular resource)

https://www.okta.com/identity-101/authentication-vs-authorization/